# How does one go about starting an UX portfolio?

Tags: wireframe, learning, portfolio

I've been visiting this site for a while and while I'm really curious about UX, I've become really frustrated switching between reading about theory and usability. I'm asking this question with the assumption that what I can do about *implementing* UX knowledge is mostly by wireframing and communicating the problems I am solving, but it seems like a nontrivial task when you don't have any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Showcasing UX is mostly about design process. I [asked a similar question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31055/how-to-showcase-ux-work) some time ago and got some good advise. From my own experience thus far, you should start by documenting your design process from sketches to wireframe and final implementation of your current project or upcoming (design)projects. Once you have sufficient amount of notes to illustrate your design process you can figure out ways to display them. Lastly, one of the most common ways to present a design process is to write a blog so that's where I'd start.